# SQL Help 'pivoting' a table in chunks

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

My database table is such that each entry is listed in a new row for each chart. I want to 'pivot' and group by ID. Do I need to use a bunch of `CASE WHEN` statements or is this a succinct way of doing this?

Here's a simplified table:

| Chart_ID | Rule | Action |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | R1 | Y |
| A1 | R3 | N |
| B4 | R1 | N |
| C1 | R1 | Y |
| C1 | R2 | N |
| C1 | R3 | Y |

I'd like a table like this:

| Chart_ID | R1 | Action1 | R2 | Action2 | R3 | Action3 | R4 | Action4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | R1 | Y |  |  | R3 | N |  |  |
| B4 | R1 | N |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| C1 | R1 | Y | R2 | N | R3 | Y |  |  |

Comment: *"Do I need to use a bunch of CASE WHEN statements"* `CASE` **expressions**, but yes, you'll want to use use conditional aggregation, which uses `CASE` expressions inside an aggregate. What did you try? Why didn't it work? There are plenty of examples and questions on how to pivot data in SQL (Server). What about those didn't you understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select chart_id,
       max(case when rule = 'R1' then rule end) as r1,
       max(case when rule = 'R1' then action end) as action1,
       max(case when rule = 'R2' then rule end) as r2,
       max(case when rule = 'R2' then action end) as action2,
       max(case when rule = 'R3' then rule end) as r3,
       max(case when rule = 'R3' then action end) as action3,
       max(case when rule = 'R4' then rule end) as r4,
       max(case when rule = 'R4' then action end) as action4
from t
group by chart_id;
```

Note that the columns `R1`, `R2`, `R3`, and `R4` are suspicious because they are redundant.  As you have defined the data, `action1` is for rule `'R1'`.